# Position element relative to window regardless of window size

Tags: javascript, css

How can I go about positioning an element in the same relative position in the viewable area of the window regardless of the window size?

For example, an element that should be:

- 30% of the window width from the left of the page, and
- 50% of the window height from the top of the page.

Comment: You want to position an element in "the same position" regardless of the viewport size. What do you define as the "the same position"? Do you mean like: "30px from the top and 20px from the right", or: "30% from the top and 20% from the right"? Or are you talking about the size of the text itself?

Comment: Yes, like for example 30% from the left and 50% from the top.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, I'm currently at school...

Comment: I've edited your question based on what I understand you're asking for and the guidelines set forth in the [help]. I am composing an answer based on the current revision. If this revision does not capture the intent of the question, please feel free to rollback the edit vision the "edited" link at the bottom of your question.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases it's possible to do this with CSS only. Did you try to use `position: fixed`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use absolute positioning and [viewport percentage lengths](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths), where one `vh` unit is 1% of the height of the viewable area and one `vw` unit is 1% of the width of the viewable area.

> Viewport-percentage lengths define the  value relative to the size of the viewport, i.e., the visible portion of the document.
>
> <sup>- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths</sup>

```css
.demo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50vh;
  left: 30vw;
  background: #AFAFAF;
}
```

```html
<div class="demo">Hello World!</div>
```